# Suddenlly 64-bit option disapeared from virtualbox and vmware. How to fix it?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, 64-bit, vmware

I have a 64-bit OS, windows 10. The hardware is a ThinkCentre 64-bits.
Until yesterday everything was ok. I was working in some vm-64bits (some in vmWare, some in VirtualBox).

The windows did an update during this night and after that I can not open the 64-bits vms. I dont have 32-bits vms, but I think 32-bits process was not affected. I still can create it.

Virtualization and Vt-d are enabled in the bios and Hyper-V are unchecked.

For sure something happened after that update.
How to bring back the 64-bits feature to vbox and vmware?

Comment: No it is not a duplicate. It is a new scenario.

Comment: What VMware product are you using?  What "64-bit option"?  You say you cannot open 64-bit VMs; does that you mean you can't power them on?  Do you get an error message?  If so, what is the message?

Comment: Just saying this is a new scenario does not mean anything. Please expand the description of your issue clarifying how your situation differs.